# how can i obtain polynomial form of a .wav(audio) file in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, curve-fitting, polynomial-math, polynomials

My teacher has given me a task of expressing a sound file(.wav) in polynomial form in MATLAB(curve fitting),.

I tried using `polyfit()` like this:-

```
 a=wavread('filename');
 x=linspace(0,1,239915);
 p=polyfit(x,a,4);
 display(p);
```

but I am getting error as

> X and Y vectors must be the same size

Please help me.

Size of a is not 239915, it is for x we have taken these many samples, for line space, by the way, why do we need x for polyfit().

Thank you in advanced

Comment: What is `m`? What is the size of `a`? I assume that `a` isn't of length `239915`.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake for writing m, instead it should be p, so i modified the question, please help me now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a = wavread('filename')
x = linspace(0, 1, numel(a))';
p = polyfit(x,a,4);
display(p)
```

Note that I transpose `linspace` output as it returns a row vector where `wavread` returns a column vector, which is why you get the error message.

Comment: Thanks, for this, I modified according to your suggestion, but still it is not working it displays same error, so any other way is there.

Comment: The same exact error? Is it a mono or stereo wave file? What does `size(a)` and `size(x)` print?